# Prioridad a Order by en lugar de Where

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Buen día a todos, la presente pregunta tiene la finalidad de encontrar como puedo generar un indicador de existencia cuando el registro se repite: porque a sido generado previamente la solicitud, a continuacion muestro la consulta relacionada:

```
SELECT id AS Existe
FROM baja_products 
WHERE 
    idGridCheck = '65860'   
    AND Aprob_ResG_Abast = 'True'  
    AND Aprob_ResG_Finan = 'True'
    AND Aprob_ResG_Gnral = 'True'
    AND Aprob_ResG_Legal = 'True'
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Ahora bien la tabla en cuestion tiene ya dos registros pq con anterioridad se aprobo el proceso para dicho item y presenta el siguiente escenario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando va mas de un row, la condicional no me brinda correctamente el indicador de existencia, por lo que se salta la validación inmersa en el Where.

La pregunta es relacionada a que puedo hacer para dar mas prioridad al order by o como puedo armar mi where para que así encuentre la coincidencia si existe un registro mas reciente tome siempre el ultimo mencionado?

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos y muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿En definitiva buscas el registro más reciente de cada `idGridCheck`? ¿El más reciente en tu modelo sería aquel cuyo `id` sea mayor?

Comment: Así es @PatricioMoracho tal cual, el id mayor es el que requiero retorne la consulta, para saber si ya todas las gerencias han aprobado o aún no lo han hecho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo sería, si en primer lugar obtenemos el mayor `id` por cada `idGridCheck` usando un `GROUP BY` y un `MAX`, luego simplemente habría que hacer un `JOIN` sobre esta subconsulta, algo así:

```
SELECT  BP.*
    FROM baja_products BP
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT     idGridCheck, MAX(id) id
                FROM baja_products 
                WHERE 
                    prob_ResG_Abast = 'True'  
                    AND Aprob_ResG_Finan = 'True'
                    AND Aprob_ResG_Gnral = 'True'
                    AND Aprob_ResG_Legal = 'True'
                GROUP BY idGridCheck
        ) M
        ON M.idGridCheck = BP.idGridCheck
        AND M.id = BP.id
    WHERE 
        BP.idGridCheck = '65860'   
        AND BP.Aprob_ResG_Abast = 'True'  
        AND BP.Aprob_ResG_Finan = 'True'
        AND BP.Aprob_ResG_Gnral = 'True'
        AND BP.Aprob_ResG_Legal = 'True'
```

A la subconsulta le quite el filtro `idGridCheck = '65860'` por si deseas ampliar eventualmente el espectro de los `idGridCheck`, pero también la puedes agregar para que sea más performante si solo necesitas consultar por un solo `idGridCheck`.

Comment: Hola Patricio buena tarde, tu respuesta me a sido de gran utilidad, saludos y muchas gracias.