# problema con DISTINCT SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo esta query que me muestra varios registros con el mismo nombre, solo quiero que me aparezca solo una vez el NombreVariable de los registros repetidos, se que es con DISTINCT pero no hace nada

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        IDVariable
        , NombreVariable
        , TipoDato
        , NumeroDecimales
        , ValorFijo
        , Activo
    , ValorIdentificadorVariable
FROM
        VariablesFormula
    WHERE
        Activo = 1
AND
    ValorIdentificadorVariable='1'
```

Comment: Inenta poner NombreVariable como primer campo despues del `DISTINCT`

Comment: @alanfcm no funciona tampoco

Comment: El `DISTINCT`actúa a nivel de fila, con que una columna ya tenga un valor diferente te lo mostrará, no es del todo claro lo que intentas, tal vez `SELECT DISTINCT NombreVariable FROM VariablesFormula   WHERE Activo = 1 AND  ValorIdentificadorVariable='1'` ?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es que necesito las otras columnas tambien...

Comment: usa group by NombreVariable de la sig. manera: SELECT * FROM VariablesFormula WHERE Activo = 1 AND ValorIdentificadorVariable='1' GROUP BY NombreVariable

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de tus datos y de la salida que queres para que te podamos ayudar mejor?

Comment: @JoseReynelChauxPerez me genera un error ----> Column 'VariablesFormula.IdVariable' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: coloca como te dice @gbianchi un ejemplo de tus datos para que podamos ayudarte mejor, relacionado así la información que arroja tu consulta...

Comment: y como es la salida que queres? eso es importante tambien

Comment: @gbianchi ya subi la salida de la query, hay registros repertidos principalmente NombreVariable es la que quiero que aparezca un solo registro sin repetirce

Comment: no. Un ejemplo de la salida que queres, ademas de la entrada que tenes. Para construir lo que necesitas, necesitamos saber que tiene que tener la salida, detalladamente

Comment: @gbianchi la salida es tener las columnas  IDVariable, NombreVariable, TipoDato , NumeroDecimales , ValorFijo , Activo , ValorIdentificadorVariable & la columna NombreVariable no se deben repetir nombres

Comment: Segun te entiendo @Ivxn seria algo similar a la sig. URL, lo que puedes hacer es seleccionar el mayor id o el mas actual y basado en ello dejar únicamente el ultimo, por  tanto te remito a la url que me parece similar a lo que requieres: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159499/prioridad-a-order-by-en-lugar-de-where

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar, supongo que estas dando tus primeros pasos en DB. si no queres que se repitan nombres, que va a poner en las otras filas? si queres solo una fila por nombre, que van en los otros campos?

Comment: si te das cuenta lo que estas haciendo es seleccionar todas las filas que contengan campos conjuntos distintos o mejor explicado, aquellas filas que el conjunto de sus columnas (IDVariable, NombreVariable, TipoDato, NumeroDecimales, ValorFijo, Activo, ValorIdentificadorVariable) se lean como si fuera un unico valor Te recomiendo que priorices las columnas que necesitas, en este caso por la columna IDVariable es que tienes esa duplicidad que imagino crees tener

Comment: Las repeticiones se dan por que tienes registros "aparentemente" repetidos con `IDVariable` distinta.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es correcto , donde uso esa query es para llenar un select donde deben aparecer sin repetir las opciones

Comment: pero el select muestra todos esos campos? o solo algunos? esto se esta extendiendo demasiado. Vuelvo a preguntar. De todos esos campos distintos, que valor queres?

Comment: Por favor califica las respuestas que recibes dentro de las preguntas que haces

Comment: Mientras en la fila que estés poyectando con la SELECT cambie algún valor de las columnas éste se mostrara. En tu caso yo eliminaría de la SELECT el IDvariable para que no te repita el mmmm.

Answer (score 2):

El distinct funciona asi:

---

```
select distinct NombreVariable from VariablesFormula

resultado: 
RegaliaAdicional
ParticipacionDelEstado
RA
BPO
```

---

```
select distinct NombreVariable, IDVariable from VariablesFormula

resultado
RegaliaAdicional, 1
RegaliaAdicional, 11
```

---

Es decir para las combinaciones de columnas que selecciones, te da como resultado los registros que son distintos